# Close a tk window on key press

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.4

Is there a way to close a tk window with the bind method? basicly I have this:

```
def foo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    E = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=folderURL)
    E.bind("<Return>", root.destroy)
```

So this doesnt work becuase its trying to send the event parameter to the destroy function that is supposed to receive just one argument (which is probably self, not sure on this one).
One solution would be to make root global and bind another function to the "Enter" event and that function would call root.destroy but I would like to do that without making root global because it dirties up my namespace for no reason, is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda function which accepts the event and calls `root.destroy()`

```
E.bind("<Return>", lambda e: root.destroy())
```

Comment: So dumb of me! im new to python so I forgot it has nested functions... thanks!